# Vector valued function; basis to change only one function at a time

Tags: derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jacobian

I have a vector valued function which takes in 3 independent variables and has three outputs and which we can represent as:
$f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, $f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, $f_3(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

The actual functions $f$ are the outputs of a FEM simulation, so I cannot write down their functional form and they are expensive to compute.

My question is the following: Is there a basis, or simply a vector in parameter space, in which only one of the functions, say $f_1$ changes?

I thought to compute the Jacobian, which informs me of the effects of changing each $x_i$ on each $f_j$. My thought was if I diagnoalize the Jacobian, the eigenvectors should form a basis in which the above condition is met. That is, if the Jacobian is diagonal in a basis, it means that each of the new coordinate s $x'_1, x'_2$ etc. affects only one of the $f_i$.

However this did not seem to work -- when I moved along these Eigenvectors it seems that one of the $f_i$ did NOT change, while the others did. This is rather the reverse of what I need, unfortunately.

Can this be done? Even if there is no exact solution, is there a way to get the vectors in phase space along which, say, $f_1$ is mostly the only one which changes?

Answer (score 1):

If $f_1$ is nice enough, its gradient tells you in what direction it changes the fastest. As a corollary (still assuming niceness), it doesn't change at all in any direction normal to the gradient. Similarly for $f_2$.

This means that if you move in a direction normal both to the gradient of $f_1$ and to the gradient of $f_2$, neither of them should change value. Such a direction is often given by the cross product of their respective gradients. Hopefully $f_3$ *does* change when moving in that direction.

Numerically, you need to evaluate a function at least for three surrounding points (in addition to the original point of interest) in order to find (an approximation to) the gradient.

Comment: Yes, I realized I could perform some procedure like this but I am looking for something a bit more systematic than "hopefully".

Comment: @user8081 Unfortunately, I don't think much can be done about that. If $f_3$ is such that it doesn't change when neither $f_1$ nor $f_2$ changes (say $f_3=f_1+f_2$, for instance), then you're out of luck: it will be impossible to change only $f_3$. That's why I said "hopefully".